# SQLite provider in VS2017

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

I want to connect sqlite using EF6 in VS2017.
I installed "System.Data.SQLite" nuget package.
I also installed "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.104.0.exe" from http://system.data.sqlite.org, but I cannot see the sqlite provider when adding ADO.NET data entity.

Am I missing something? or the above package not supporting VS2017 (it said it is for VS2015)

Comment: Dev calls it "extremely difficult" https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/3ff30ce88a12bc39

Answer (score 28):

There is no DDEX provider package for VS 2017 (yet). https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=8292431f51

Basically you need to wait for: sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2017-1.0.1xx.0.exe

"Official" update:

> The current estimate is that support for Visual Studio 2017 will
> be included in the 1.0.106.0 release, which should be released at
> some point in the mid-June timeframe.
>
> mistachkin added on 2017-05-28 20:41:40: At this point, it seems unlikely that I'll be able to add VS 2017 support for the design-time components (e.g. table designer, entity wizard, etc).

**UPDATE:** I have created a DDEX provider that enables SQLite support (for EF6 only) in Visual Studio 2017, see the how-to guide here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: Currently scheduled for April 2017. (That ticket was mine btw :))

Comment: Doesn't seem like 1.0.105.0 has addressed VS2017 support. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You are right, I cannot see the expected package either - time for a new ticket?

Comment: It looks like they gave up o_O

Comment: I have now created a DDEX provider you can try: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Release-notes

Comment: Update on this 

`mistachkin added on 2017-05-28 20:41:40:
At this point, it seems unlikely that I'll be able to add VS 2017 support
for the design-time components (e.g. table designer, entity wizard, etc).`

Doesn't bode well...

Comment: @ErikEJ have you considered offering your assistant to the sqlite team? 
mistachkin, seems very open to outside assistance on the matter. Having to add another extension to visual studio, isn't exactly optimal, with that said, I am using your provider now.

Comment: @BruceBurge I have considered this, but system.data.sqlite is the most closed source oss project I know, with proprietsry source control, issue tracker and build system. When they move to github and accept PRs, then I will reconsider

Comment: Thanks for the effort, ErikEJ, but as far as I am concerned, if it does not work with the Data Configuration Wizard in VS 2017, your solution is of very little use.

Comment: Is there a way to drag and drop tables onto a DataSet with it?

Comment: @jriv No, as I wrote, it is for EF6 support only!

Comment: Sad, It's not worth changing data table class, and that DotConnect alternative seems full of bugs and quirks (and it even charges the full version).

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in your wiki page. I now have the Toolbox installed and the About dialog says "SQLite EF6 DBProvider in GAC - Yes". I have added all SQLite packages into the project too. Yet I cannot see SQLite provider in the EDM New Connection dialog. This is VS2017 Community. Any hints?

Comment: @dotNET  try to restart VS and use Server Explorer to verify that the SQLite Provider (Simple by ErikEJ) is available

Comment: @dotNET I have added more diagnostics information to the About dialog in the latest daily build

Comment: OK, Server Explorer does show `SQLite Provider (Simple by ErikEJ)` option, but EDM's New Connection doesn't. What would that mean?

Comment: Here's text from About dialog: 
`Version 4.7.251.0 - 847,050 downloads
SQL Server Compact 4.0 in GAC - Yes - 4.0.8876.1
SQL Server Compact 4.0 DbProvider - Yes
SQL Server Compact 4.0 DDEX provider - No
SQL Server Compact 4.0 Simple DDEX provider - Yes
SQL Server Compact 3.5 in GAC - Yes - 3.5.8080.0
SQL Server Compact 3.5 DbProvider - Yes
SQL Server Compact 3.5 DDEX provider - No
Sync Framework 2.1 SqlCe 3.5 provider - No
SQLite ADO.NET Provider included: 1.0.105.1
SQLite EF6 DbProvider in GAC - Yes`

Comment: Could this have any link to the fact that I'm using the new `PackageReference` scheme and not `packages.config`?

Comment: There's something fishy going on. Even after installing 105.2, the About dialog still shows 105.1 in it. I'm going to uninstall and reinstall things.

Comment: I finally got it working. Not 100% sure of the exact causes, but this has got something to do with the new `PackageReference` scheme. I manually removed all nuget packages from my project in VS2017, then opened the project in VS2015, added all the packages back to get my `packages.config` again (VS2015 supports that scheme only). Afterwards I came back to VS2017 and tried EDM's New Connection dialog again. And there you go!

Comment: @dotNET Glad you got it working, the EF Tools have not been tested with the new project system

Comment: @dotNet I had exactly the same problem as you describe in your comments, but a simple re-build of my project solved it—and seems to have done so consistently and repeatedly. Maybe that’s what was happening in your case, too?

Comment: Here again after about 2 years. VS2017 support is still not there; while VS2019 is around the corner. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved after installing SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox.
Please try. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2017 installer is really a pain in the b***.. Installing packages via an automated deployment works, but detecting installation state and such is near to impossible..

Seems like microsoft devs finally got sick of msi packages and implemented their own installer / package manager for VS2017, as other teams did for Office 365 and such..

Comment: Use vsWhere and related tools/APIs

Answer (score 0):

According to the url provided by the sqlite-netFX46-bundle-win32-2015-1.0.108.0 intaller log : https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/8292431f51119807241632b092774e60189018d9 Visual Studio 2017 support isn't available yet
I tryied many things without any result, the worst is that I  installed also a VS 2015 but cannot install because of the VS 2017 installation on my computer.