# Making a C# SQLite Database first model appear out of thin air

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am trying to make a tiny application, using SQLite and EF6.

I already have an SQLite database with tables and data, so I want to create a model and populate it from that. However despite everything I've tried I have had no success.
When adding a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" I have no option for SQLite database (this is on Visual Studio 2015).

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330352/generating-sqlite-database-from-model-at-vs-2015-ef7) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_database_first_approach.htm).

**What I have done so far:**
- First tried to simply install SQLite by NuGet - no luck.
- Then I created a new project, and instead of NuGet installed the latest x32 System.Data.SQLite setup package and made sure to check the option of installing design-time components for Visual Studio 2015 - no dice
- Then I saw someone had luck with installing an older version of the setup packages. After a painstaking installation (after removing the newer version) - no cigar.
- So I started following [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0) and, hooray - I can't add the assemblies, despite telling the setup to put them in the Global Trash Can or whatever.

So I come to you, dear people, hoping someone can wave a magic wand and help me get this thing that's supposed to be tiny, fast and easy to be, you guessed it - at all working.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you on?

Comment: This could be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796069/982149

Comment: @Fildor, thank you for bringing this to my attention - I added the version information to the question (it's 2015), I also took a look at the linked question and will now investigate further.

Comment: @Fildor, oh God... it's there... the option is there... I'm so happy I could cry right now ;_;    Blessed be your tiny nickname, Fildor! Still I wonder why it didn't work with 2015...