# SQLite with Entity Framework. System.Data.SQLite Database File is not showing in data source

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I have problem with create a new ADO.NET entity data model. I want to connect to my local sqlite database but when I'm trying to add new connection I can't see `System.Data.SQLite` database file. I tried everything and I still can't find a solution. I installed sqlite for x32 to 4.6 .NET and I'm using same version in my project.

Here is my app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

and packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.109.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.109.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.109.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.109.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to install a package saying "**This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 20xx**" and choose the one for your Visual Studio version from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki . Unfortunaly, there isn't one for VS2017, you can read more about it here [SQLite provider in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792402/sqlite-provider-in-vs2017) .